# Box-API: How can I add a strong name to a 3rd party assembly written for the .NET Portable Subset

Tags: box-api, portable-class-library, strongname, assembly-signing

I am trying to strongly name a 3rd party API that I have the code for but it's using a 3rd party DLL/NuGet Package that is also not strongly named and I'm having a lot of trouble.

I'm using the Box Windows SDK and the API was written in the .NET portable subset and supports .NET for Windows Store Apps, .NET Framework 4 and higher, SL4 and higher, and Windows Phone 7 and higher. Granted, I do not need all of these but I do need the .NET 4 and Silverlight versions. The API already works wonderfully and runs fine on its own. It would with my application also, if all my projects were unsigned but they aren't. We use strongly named assemblies for our Silverlight application in order to make use of application library caching.

Anyway, I have the source code for the API so I simply added my PFX file to the project to sign it. I then get an error that a dependency that this API is using called NitoAsnycEx.dll is not signed. I do not have the code for Nito.AsyncEx.dll but normally this isn't such a problem, more of an annoyance. So now I have an age-old problem of needing to take a 3rd party DLL of which I don't have code for and sign it with my PFX or another SNK file.

I can do either and normally I use one of the processes so wonderfully explained in this post by Ian Picknell: http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2009/12/adding-strong-name-to-third-party.html. So I have followed that process and the IL signing tools seem to sign the DLL just fine.

To make a long story shorter, let's use the simplest version of the signing process where I already have a simple SNK file ready to go. Basically, I do this:

1. I can run ILDASM to get the .il file for this 3rd party EXE:

   ILDASM Nito.AsyncEx.dll /out:Nito.AsyncEx.il
2. I can then run ILASM to get the signed DLL:

   ILASM Nito.AsyncEx.il /dll /resource=Nito.AsyncEx.res /key=NPSAssemblyKeyNoPassword.snk

It works great and I get this result:

> ```
> Method Implementations (total): 118
> Resolving local member refs: 0 -> 0 defs, 0 refs, 0 unresolved
> Writing PE file
>  Signing file with strong name
> Operation completed successfully
> ```

So now I have a signed DLL. I go back to my 3rd Party API code and remove the old reference to NitoAsyncEx.dll and put a new one to this. I try to compile and then I get an error like this:

```
Error   44  The base class or interface 'System.Object' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by type 'Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncLock' could not be resolved  r:\Data\GM\Source\GrantManagement\GrantManagement\3rd Party\Nito\Nito.AsyncEx.dll
```

I figure there is some problems using the portable .net library here but I'm not sure what it is. This same process normally works for me for Silverlight 4+ and Full .NET 4.5 framework libraries. Is there another ILASM or ILDASM set somewhere that will disassemble and reassemble the portable code correctly? Is this even possible?

I also tried to go and get the source code for the NitoAsyncEx.dll, which is open source btw, and compile it but that source code will not compile as it's missing some files. So currently I'm stuck with my integration of this API into my project and need a little assistance from any experts in the community.

Is there a way to sign this DLL correctly so we're not missing references to basic classes such as System.Object?

Is there a way to get around needing to sign this DLL at all and having it referenced from my projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

The Box SDK has been updated and is now strong-named on nuget. This is thanks to the recent update to AsyncEx which strong-named the assembly.

---

As you mentioned, it's unfortunately out of our control that the NitoAsyncEx library is not strongly named. This library provides the ability to properly lock resources during an async/await call, and I do not believe there is a better alternative at the moment.

This being said, I may have a (hopefully temporary) workaround for you. I've downloaded the source from https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/ and was able to get it to compile. These are the steps I performed:

- Removed the reference to MSBuild in the csproj
- Copied the missing Dequeue.cs file from the packages folder
- Resolved missing nuget references
- Regenerated the AssemblyInfo.cs
- Excluded the .tt template files from the project
- Unloaded all other projects the SDK does not use

Here's the resulting solution:
https://cloud.box.com/s/7ikurtyajqmhq9p8q52x

I've successfully ran the resulting dll through the SDK's tests so hopefully this should cover what you need. I cannot guarantee the stability of this method, but having a working source should allow you to do any signing you need. From there, you should be able to drop the signed assembly into the SDK source and sign that assembly as well.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I tried about half of the things you listed to get the Nito.AsnycEx.dll code to compile and many others but not the things that finally made it work. This is actually a fairly decent work around. Seeing that the NitoAsyncEx project hasn't been updated in quite some time according to the source code, I do not see it changing much and if it doesn't, and Box continues to use it, when you update your API I will simply grab it and try replacing the Nito reference with this one.

Comment: I could be calling this a bit prematurely, becuase I haven't actually used the Box API since I signed and updated the NITO dll, but I think this is going to be the propert resolution.  Thank you very much for the quick turn around, I was really stuck on this.

Comment: as a FYI, the Box v2 sdk is now strong-named on nuget. Original post updated to reflect this change as well.